# Discord bot how do i make a bot delete text channels?

Tags: discord.js

How could i example, make it so if someone does !delete, it would delete that channel

Also, how would i turn that into another command that can wipe all text channels

Answer (score 1):

You can delete a channel with [`Channel.delete()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Channel?scrollTo=delete). If you'd like to delete the channel a command was sent in, you can do something like this:

```js
message.channel.delete.catch(console.error);
```

---

To delete all channels, you can use [`Collection.each()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection?scrollTo=each)

```js
// iterate a function through all channels in a guild
message.guild.channels.cache.each((channel) =>
  channel.delete().catch(console.error));
```